# Upload multiple images and convert to base64 before saving to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I got a form which permits to upload multiple images. I then collect these images, upload them to a file in the app and convert them to base64 strings before saving the strings to the database.

Below is what I got already :

View :

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 ">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.VueSiegeArriere, new { @class = "control-label", })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.VueSiegeArriere, new { @class = "form-control", type = "file", accept = "image/x-png,image/jpeg", id = "VueSiegeArriere" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 ">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.VueSiegeAvant, new { @class = "control-label", })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.VueSiegeAvant, new { @class = "form-control", type = "file", accept = "image/x-png,image/jpeg", id = "VueSiegeAvant" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddVoiture(VoitureVM v, HttpPostedFileBase VueFace, HttpPostedFileBase VueArriere, HttpPostedFileBase VueGauche, HttpPostedFileBase VueDroite, HttpPostedFileBase VueSiegeArriere, HttpPostedFileBase VueSiegeAvant, HttpPostedFileBase MalleArriere, HttpPostedFileBase TableauBord)

    {
        Voiture Car = new Voiture();

        v.VueFace = UploadandConvertImage(VueFace);
        v.VueGauche = UploadandConvertImage(VueGauche);
        v.VueSiegeArriere = UploadandConvertImage(VueSiegeArriere);
        v.VueSiegeAvant = UploadandConvertImage(VueSiegeAvant);
        v.VueDroite = UploadandConvertImage(VueDroite);
        v.TableauBord = UploadandConvertImage(TableauBord);
        v.VueArriere = UploadandConvertImage(VueArriere);
        v.MalleArriere = UploadandConvertImage(MalleArriere);

        return RedirectToAction("Liste");
        //return View(v);
    }
```

UploadandConvertImage method which I call in the controller:

```
string base64String;
    private string UploadandConvertImage(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {

        if (file != null)
        {
            string pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Pictures/Voitures"), pic);
            // file is uploaded
            file.SaveAs(path);

            //wish to convert the uploaded images to base64 and store them in database
            using (System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(path))
            {
                using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
                    byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();
                    base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
                    //return base64String;
                }
            }
        }
        return base64String;
    }
```

Saving to database :

```
//Let's now insert details into the table ImagesVoitures
        ImagesVoiture carImages = new ImagesVoiture();

        carImages.VueFace = voiture.VueFace;
        carImages.VueGauche = voiture.VueGauche;
        carImages.VueDroite = voiture.VueDroite;
        carImages.VueSiegeArriere = voiture.VueSiegeArriere;
        carImages.VueSiegeAvant = voiture.VueSiegeAvant;
        carImages.TableauBord = voiture.TableauBord;
        carImages.MalleArriere = voiture.MalleArriere;
        carImages.VueArriere = voiture.VueArriere;

        bdd.ImagesVoiture.Add(carImages);
        bdd.SaveChanges();
```

What I expect to get are the base64 strings which I can save to the respective fields in the database.

What I actually get is an SQLException which says :

> System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException : 'Échec de
>   la validation d'une ou de plusieurs entités. Pour plus d'informations,
>   consultez 'EntityValidationErrors'.'

Comment: Which part you are having trouble with ? The uploading /converting to base 64 ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Just wanted to point out, you kinda need to ask us a question...

Comment: @CaiusJard thanks for welcoming me. It's just an error if I posted the question incomplete. I just edited it.

Comment: What is the reason for converting to Base64? That will *increase* the storage space required as well as the time and steps to convert back to image.  Most all DB can store binary data (like images)

Comment: Just a tip, french error text is probably going to decrease the chances for somebody to help you.

Comment: OP I suggest you *consultez les EntityValidationErrors* as instructed by the exception message. Post back what you find and any relevant validation rules in the entity.

Comment: Wrap your code with a `try`-`catch` and check the `EntityValidationErrors` on the exception.

Comment: @WelcomeOverflow, please could you be kind to tell me what's your advice on what is the method I should rather use to manage uploaded images?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is not coming from the code you've posted. In this code I don't see that you're saving to a database either.

It looks like your `Voiture` model has validation on it. The strings you are assigning to the `car` instance of `Voiture` are probably not passing validation.

I may be making a mistake, but it looks like you're posting images, turning them to base64 strings and returning them back to the client or view.

Did I miss something?

Comment: yes that's approximately what I'm doing. When I upload the images, I turn them to base64 strings and return them back to the client view after reconverting them to images. It's true that the model "ImagesVoiture" which contains the fields for saving the images as strings have the Stringlength attribute set to 255. Maybe that could be the source of the SQLException i'm getting?